# IllegalStateException due to a detached fragment when trying to use context

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, illegalstateexception

I have a fragment that has an `AsyncTask` running a list population job. Inside the `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` I use the method `getString()` to, get a string. I've had an IllegalStateException thrown a couple of times there, but the strange thing is that I kill the `AsyncTask` in the fragments `onDetach()`.

My AsyncTask code is pretty much:

```
myTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(){
          //code...
         String message;
          //code...
         if(//some eval){
           message = mContext.getString(R.string.Eval_true) <= Causes exception in rare cases
         }
    }
}
```

And in the fragment's onDetach method I do:

```
@Override
public void onDetach(){
  if(myTask != null && myTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
      myTask.cancel(true);
  }
  super.onDetach();
}
```

Now as I said, this has only happened 2-3 times during maybe 150 - 200 runs, but I'd still like to find out what could be causing the task cancel on fragment detach to not work in some cases.

All hints are appreciated.

-MrDresden

Comment: Do you check inside your AsyncTask if it is cancelled / use code that can be interrupted (`throws InterruptedException`)? Android does not magically kill tasks. The task has to check if it should stop.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for helping out. I am using `isCancelled()` to check if the task has been killed but not before that `getString()` line. It makes sense now looking at it, that the context gets nullified when the fragment gets detached from the activity. I'll just do another `isCancelled()` call before that line and that should be that.